# What is difference between deleteOne() and findOneAndDelete() operation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This both operations delete one object. Is there any performance difference between them or both are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findOneAndDelete has the `sort` parameter which can be used to influence which document is updated. It also has a TimeLimit parameter which can control within which operation has to complete.

From the docs : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/

> Deletes a single document based on the filter and sort criteria,
>   returning the deleted document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/

> Removes a single document from a collection.